# How can I grab all rows from one table, but filter the second table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running a query on a PHP page that will pull all records from one table, INNER JOIN with two other tables and then list all of the results. However on the second table I only want the most recent record.

Here is my query

```
SELECT * FROM wn_trailer 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, trailer_id, trailer_status, trailer_assigned, MAX(last_update), trailer_lat, trailer_long
    FROM wn_trailer_history
) AS th ON wn_trailer.id = th.trailer_id 
INNER JOIN wn_trailer_status ON wn_trailer_status.id = th.trailer_status 
INNER JOIN wn_users ON wn_users.id = th.trailer_assigned 
ORDER BY trailer_number ASC
```

The query runs but returns only the first record.

Comment: @BrandonPratt `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax. near '() OVER(        PARTITION BY trailer_id ORDER BY last_update '`

Comment: Sorry about that, try `INNER JOIN (SELECT trailer_id, trailer_status, trailer_assigned, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY trailer_id ORDER BY last_update DESC) AS RowNum FROM wn_trailer_history) AS th ON wn_trailer.id = th.trailer_id AND th.RowNum = 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want an additional `JOIN` to bring in the data on the last update date.  Also, your subquery needs a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM wn_trailer t INNER JOIN
     (SELECT trailer_id, MAX(last_update) as max_last_update
      FROM wn_trailer_history
      GROUP BY trailer_id
     ) tht
     ON t.id = tht.trailer_id INNER JOIN
     wn_trailer_history th
     ON th.trailer_id = tht.trailer_id AND
        th.last_update = tht.max_last_update INNER JOIN
     wn_trailer_status ts
     ON ts.id = th.trailer_status INNER JOIN
     wn_users u
     ON u.id = th.trailer_assigned 
ORDER BY trailer_number ASC;
```

I also added table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.

Comment: There is a typo `tht.max_last_udpate`, but it works, thank you!